# Add categories automatically - Unique constraint violation found

Tags: magento2, php, category

I added two categories with sub-categories from my ERP with an integration.

When I want to edit a category, I have an error "Unique constraint violation found".

Do you know how I can resolve this issue?

[image]

Log:

> [code][2018-02-20 14:05:21] main.CRITICAL: Unique constraint violation
>   found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0):
>   Unique constraint violation found at
>   /home/magento/www/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php:121,
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException(code: 1062):
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'infusion-low-temp-curing/Rubber.html-1' for key
>   'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO
>   url_rewrite (`redirect_ty.. [/code]

Comment: Are you editing or adding a new category?

Comment: Check your logs there should be more information about the constraint violated

Answer (score 1):

The error log says that you are trying to do another insert with the same combination of columns that belong to `URL_REWRITE` table. The table is defied as **UNIQUE** and is not allowing same combination to be inserted twice.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the system triy to do another insert with the same combination when I want to save a modification on an existing category?

Comment: I had a very similar problem before, however, it was happening when customer tried to place an order and order could not be created because it it trying to assign an already existing order number (which has to be unique too). It happened because of customer session not being closed after purchase for some reason. I fixed it by deleting the entry in the corresponding table and since then everything is running as it should.

Comment: If that helped you resolve the issue please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @BareFeet i have a similar issue here to your one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220833/unique-constraint-violation-intermittent-at-checkout-magento-2-2-3 I was wondering if you could take a look and see if it is acutally the same and shine some light on which table you deleted entries from?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue when attempting to enable / disable categories on my website.

After investigation I found that the URL Key for the category was the root cause of my issue. For example "Tumble Dryers" was saving into the URL_Rewrite table as "Tumble Dryers.html".

I then went back through the categories in the URL_Rewrite change and changed the URLs to be in the following format "tumble-dryers.html". After this I attempted the change again via the Admin panel which then saved without the error.