# Unique Constraint Violation Intermittent at Checkout - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have had this issue intermittently (1 in about 20-30 orders) for a while now not sure when it started possible anywhere from version 2.1.7 and not sure what has caused this. I am using **Form Integration** from **Ebizmarts Sage Pay Suite** module. I thought it was due to this plugin however this may not be the case and they believe it is an issue within my Magento instance.

**Orders** do seem to work however error is shown on **checkout success** and anywhere from **2 - 7 emails** seem to end up in both our and customer inboxes when this occurs.

The following **error** is shown in my logs when above occurs:

```
SagePaySuiteLogger.Exception: Unique constraint violation found
```

### Full Trace:

```
[2018-03-29 08:26:44] SagePaySuiteLogger.Exception: Unique constraint violation found
#0 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction))
#1 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/ebizmarts/sagepaysuite/Model/OrderUpdateOnCallback.php(72): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#2 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/ebizmarts/sagepaysuite/Controller/Form/Success.php(172): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Model\OrderUpdateOnCallback->confirmPayment('B1B897CC-D94C-4...')
#3 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success->execute()
#4 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#6 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Controller/Form/Success/Interceptor.php(26): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#8 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#17 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#19 /home/sites/magento/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#20 {main}
```

I have looked at below link as seems to be a very similar issue however my tables look in tact according to the images in this post: https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-unique-constraint-violation-found-magento-2-checkout-after-migration/

The only difference that can be seen is that my `prefix` entry is null for the `meta_id` referring to entries for `store_id`'s 0 and 1 and i have max / warning values set for `store_id` 2.

Can anyone suggest what may be **causing** this issue with my **checkout** or how to help further **debug** this issue?

### Code that throws error

```
    try {
        if (!$this->isModified($object)) {
            $this->processNotModifiedSave($object);
            $this->commit();
            $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
            return $this;
        }
        $object->validateBeforeSave();
        $object->beforeSave();
        if ($object->isSaveAllowed()) {
            $this->_serializeFields($object);
            $this->_beforeSave($object);
            $this->_checkUnique($object);
            $this->objectRelationProcessor->validateDataIntegrity($this->getMainTable(), $object->getData());
            if ($this->isObjectNotNew($object)) {
                $this->updateObject($object);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewObject($object);
            }
            $this->unserializeFields($object);
            $this->processAfterSaves($object);
        }
        $this->addCommitCallback([$object, 'afterCommitCallback'])->commit();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
    } catch (DuplicateException $e) {
        $this->rollBack();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(true);
        throw new AlreadyExistsException(new Phrase('Unique constraint violation found'), $e);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->rollBack();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(true);
        throw $e;
    }
```

Or what line causes the `throw new AlreadyExistsException(new Phrase('Unique constraint violation found'), $e);` to be thrown so i can maybe log some information about why it is thrown?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this as I am having the exact same issue

Comment: Literally been putting checkouts through all day today to see if i can make it happen. Do you use Ebizmarts sage pay? It very rarely happens, can you explain a bit more about when yours happens also?

Comment: I have Magento 2.2.2 with Ebizmarts Sagepay 1.2.4. 

Sagepay states: "Transaction completed but Vendor systems returned INVALID or ERROR in response to notification POST. Transaction CANCELLED by the Vendor. "

When looking in the logs we have  ["Ebizmarts\\SagePaySuite\\Controller\\Server\\Notify::cancelOrder",254] []
 SagePaySuiteLogger.Exception: Unique constraint violation found

Comment: Yeah seems very similar. Have you contacted Ebizmarts? They are telling me it is my magento. Where did you get this information ""Transaction completed but Vendor systems returned INVALID or ERROR in response to notification POST. Transaction CANCELLED by the Vendor. "?

Comment: But yeah im on 2.2.3 with 1.2.4 but have had this issue a while so would of existed when i was on 2.2.1 at least

Comment: Ebizmarts are saying the same to me to, thats its Magento and not them. But it doesn't look like it is Magento

I saw that error in SagePay when you click on the failed order

Comment: Yeah, i cant make it happen with any normal magento payment method like Bank transfer. Is this with the Form integration?

Comment: I am using server integration

Comment: Hmm yeah they were suggesting i switch integration however it seems like that wont help either. For PCI I was going to either iframe or redirect for scope and hope that the other method works but may have to find the problem at source.

Comment: We are using the iframe method in server

Comment: Yeah it seems exact same issue however. I will keep trying to figure this out and if i do will update here on how to fix it although i do not feel close to figuring this one out if im honest.

Comment: we might have identified where the issue lies. we are working on a fix and will release a new version of the extension for Magento 2.2.x soon.

Comment: @PabloS.Benitez Awesome news thanks for the update. So your from ebizmarts? Let us know on here how it goes. Thanks again Harri

Comment: Im not sure we are going to be able to release today (still testing), its going to be tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use version 1.2.6 for Magento 2.2.x. 
Upgrade via composer.

Comment: Will try as soon as i get a chance thanks for the update.