# magento 2 Unique constraint violation found when adding subcategory

Tags: magento2, product, category, url-rewrite, magento2.4.3.p1

I added two categories with sub-categories from my magento site with multiple websites 2.4.3-p1.
i have imported 100 products assigned products to main category through sheet.
after that created subcategory and trying to assign products to subcategory using admin pannel getting

Unique constraint violation found {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0): Unique constraint violation found

i have checked below links

[Add categories automatically - Unique constraint violation found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214254/add-categories-automatically-unique-constraint-violation-found)

["Unique constraint violation found" Error When Assign Product into Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277073/unique-constraint-violation-found-error-when-assign-product-into-category)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Category-generating-weird-issues-in-url-rewrites-and-adding-to-a/td-p/424911

["Unique constraint violation found" Error When Assign Product into Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277073/unique-constraint-violation-found-error-when-assign-product-into-category)

Comment: Try applying this patch https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-12/mdva-42689-users-get-integrity-constraint-violation-error-while-updating-product-categories.html?lang=en

Comment: @LokeshNaik applied but still not fixed issue